# Strange error after upgrading to Xcode 3.2.5 ld: file not found: -miphoneos-version-min=3.2

Tags: iphone, xcode3.2

I have been banging my head on this for a while now. What is the problem? btw. I am using the Three20 Libraries in my project in case that has anything to do with.

Ld build/DFJ.build/Debug-iphoneos/DFJ.build/Objects-normal/armv6/DFJ normal armv6
cd /Users/macuser/Dropbox/DFJ/DFJ
setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 3.2
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++-4.2 -arch armv6 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk -L/Users/macuser/Dropbox/DFJ/DFJ/build/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/macuser/Dropbox/DFJ/DFJ/build/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/macuser/Dropbox/DFJ/DFJ/../../../Downloads/gdata-objectivec-client-1.11.0/Source/build/Debug -filelist /Users/macuser/Dropbox/DFJ/DFJ/build/DFJ.build/Debug-iphoneos/DFJ.build/Objects-normal/armv6/DFJ.LinkFileList -dead_strip -all_load -force_load -miphoneos-version-min=3.2 -framework QuartzCore -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -lsqlite3.0 -framework MobileCoreServices -lxml2 -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration -framework OpenAL -framework CoreAudio -framework AudioToolbox -o /Users/macuser/Dropbox/DFJ/DFJ/build/DFJ.build/Debug-iphoneos/DFJ.build/Objects-normal/armv6/DFJ

ld: file not found: -miphoneos-version-min=3.2
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++-4.2 failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are getting that error because of this part of the `ld` command line:

```
-force_load -miphoneos-version-min=3.2
```

The `-force_load` option expects to be followed by a filename, but no filename is present so it's taking the next option (`-miphoneos-version-min=3.2`) and trying to interpret it as a filename.

Take a look at your build settings in XCode to see where that `-force_load` flag is being specified...